# For Exoplayer, can I add (or enable?) a button to toggle Closed Captions using the standard controls, e.g. in PlayerControlView?

Tags: exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

My app is playing video streams with Exoplayer.

I am using the default controls by using "PlayerControlView".

I need to add a toggle button to show/hide closed captions ( subtitles ).

Is there a simple way to add such a button to the standard controls?

( Note: I am aware that it's possible to completely customize the controls by creating custom views and firing events on Exoplayer, that's not what I'm asking here. )

Put in a different way: What's the easiest way to have a toggle button for toggling the visibility of closed captions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to add button to MediaControlView. You need to use your exo_playback_control_view.xml in your own resource directory.